# What is the best way to remove latex paint from a shower liner?

Tags: shower, paint-removal, stain-removal

What is the best way to remove latex paint from a shower liner? The shower I have has a one piece liner along three walls.  It looks like it was painted with latex paint which is now peeling off. Behind the paint I can see a brownish yellow stain on the surface which is probably why the previous owner painted over it.  So I hope there is some way to clean that ugly stained color as well.  So there are two questions here:

1. How to remove the latex paint
2. How to remove those ugly stains on the liner

Comment: Pressure washer or steam cleaner?

Comment: The combination of paint and stains make me think it's time to consider replacement.

Comment: Before trying to remove the paint, would see if the stains are removable.  Decent chance that they have gone inside the surface and the only way would be to remove the surface by sanding, which ruins the surface.  If stains don't come out with cleansers and stiff brush/pads, might need to live with them.

Comment: Latex paint I'd think would just peal right off or easily scraped. As for stains, bleach or  some type of scale/mold remover.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tip I found for stripping paint from furniture, Easy Off Oven Cleaner. I used it on a 50 year old breaker box cover panel someone had covered with wall paint. It worked great to remove deteriorated latex top coat while leaving the original enamel that was underneath. Leave it 10 minutes or so, scrape off and rinse with water. Ensure good ventilation.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach for a _steel_ breaker box cover. I'm not so certain that it would work on a _fiberglass or plastic_ shower surround. It might end up doing more damage to the fiberglass or plastic than good. The usual suggestion of testing it on a small, inconspicuous location applies, however, there probably isn't a good place to test it that might not cause further problems (water leaks) should the cleaner cause damage.